# Omines datatables and column width

Tags: symfony, datatables

I try to use Omines datatables bundle with symfony (4) but I can't force the columns width...
I've seen this page
https://github.com/omines/datatables-bundle/issues/71
so i tried the proposed solution but this is as if i didn't do anything : all my columns have the same width.

Did i forget something ?

Here is my controller :

```
    public function actionList2(Request $request, DataTableFactory $dataTableFactory): Response
    {
    $options = [
        'fixedHeader' => false,
        'serverSide' => false,
        'processing' => true,
        'searching' => true,
        'autoWidth' => false,
        'columnFilter' => 'both',
        'pageLength' => null,
        'paging' => false,
    ];

    $table = $dataTableFactory->create($options)
        ->add('actCod', TextColumn::class, ['label' => 'Code', 'searchable' => true, 'filter' => ['templateHTML' => 'datatables/Filter/text.html.twig', 'placeholder' => null]])
        ->add('actLib', TextColumn::class, ['label' => 'Libellé', 'searchable' => true, 'filter' => ['templateHTML' => 'datatables/Filter/text.html.twig', 'placeholder' => null]])
        ->add('actIdMere', TextColumn::class, ['label' => 'Action mère', 'searchable' => true, 'filter' => ['templateHTML' => 'datatables/Filter/text.html.twig', 'placeholder' => null]])
        ->add('actDatCmd', DateTimeColumn::class, ['label' => 'Commande', 'searchable' => true, 'filter' => ['templateHTML' => 'datatables/Filter/text.html.twig', 'placeholder' => null]])
        ->add('actDatMep', DateTimeColumn::class, ['label' => 'MEP', 'searchable' => true, 'filter' => ['templateHTML' => 'datatables/Filter/text.html.twig', 'placeholder' => null]])
        ->add('actUsrCre', TextColumn::class, ['label' => 'User Cre', 'searchable' => true, 'filter' => ['templateHTML' => 'datatables/Filter/text.html.twig', 'placeholder' => null]])
        ->add('actDatCre', DateTimeColumn::class, ['label' => 'Date Cre', 'searchable' => true, 'filter' => ['templateHTML' => 'datatables/Filter/text.html.twig', 'placeholder' => null]])
        ->add('actDatMod', DateTimeColumn::class, ['label' => 'Date Mod', 'searchable' => true, 'filter' => ['templateHTML' => 'datatables/Filter/text.html.twig', 'placeholder' => null]])
        ->createAdapter(ORMAdapter::class, ['entity' => V8Action::class
        ])
        ->handleRequest($request);

    if ($table->isCallback()) {
        return $table->getResponse();
    }

    return $this->render('list2.html.twig', ['datatable' => $table]);

}
```

And my twig...

```
{# /templates/list.html.twig #}
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block titre %}liste{% endblock%}

{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}
{% endblock%}

{% block page_content %}
<a href="{{ path('home') }}">Home</a><br/>

<div id="list">Loading...</div>

{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('list2') }}
    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#list').initDataTables({{ datatable_settings(datatable) }}
           ,{
                columnDefs: [
                    {width: "30%", targets: [1]},
                ]
            }
        );
    });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

The width of the column is not used.

However, i put a console.log in Omines datatable.js :

```
    root.html(data.template);
    dt = $('table', root).DataTable(dtOpts);
    console.log(dtOpts);
```

and i can see my columnDefs in dtOpts oO

Answer (score 0):

I've used omines datatables in my pet project.
I'm not sure what exactly is wrong in your case but what I can see is that your code of table field configuration differs from mine. 
If you need something like this:
[image]

you could check my repo and compare, hope it could help you to pinpoint your problem
https://github.com/mainstreamer/base-home/blob/master/src/Controller/PlaceController.php

Comment: Thank for your answer. The thing wrong in my case is that i can't find a way to tell Datatable the column width and min width i want it to respect in my tables. My app has really thousands of tables and the automated layout is sometime rather messy. I'd like to be able to fix a width for some column, a min width for others (it may need scrollX). Whatever i do, Datatable decides what is better for me. Except if i put 'table-layout: fixed' but then, it is fixed. I can't manage cases like "width: 30%; min-width: 15em". CSS is not used and datatables column width properties are overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I've done like this in my twig

```
table2 = $('#Dcfdatatables').initDataTables({{ datatable_settings(datatable) }} , {
"pageLength": 10,
dom: '<"top"lf>rt<"bottom"ip><"clear">',
"lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100,
columnDefs: [
    {width: "4%", targets: 0, title:"<input type='checkbox' id='select_all' name='select_all'>"},
    {width: "6%", targets: 1},
    {width: "13%", targets: 2},
    {width: "7%", targets: 3},
    {width: "26%", targets: 4},
    {width: "22%", targets: 5},
    {width: "12%", targets: 6},
    {width: "10%", targets: 7},
],initComplete: function(){
...
}
```

Works for me.